# List all matching 5 byte binary fields with 3 byte search input

Tags: php, mysql

i write card ids in a mysql table.
The column (cardno) is a 5 byte binary in hex (value example: 0600747CF8).

id | cardno

1  | 0600747CF8

2  | 0300973D8A

3  | ...

i try to find entries that match on the first (lowest) 3 bytes with 3 byte search input (expamle: 747CF8).

How can i find matching  rows with those searching input?

With hole 5 byte as search input it works with `SELECT` and the exaclty known hex number.

Answer (score 0):

i got it:

```
SELECT *, HEX(`cardno`) AS `cardno` FROM `cards` WHERE INSTR(cardno,UNHEX('747CF8')) > 0;
```